# Mathematica returns a blank coordinate system when I try to plot data

Tags: plotting, data

I used two very simple commands to plot the first data set, and it worked out perfectly:

```
data = Import["E:\\Hysteresekurve.txt", {"Data", {All}, {2, 3}}];
ListPlot @ data
```

For my next plot, I imported this txt file into Excel, did the necessary calculations and then exported the spreadsheet to a new txt where the newly calculated data has its own column. Next I tried to plot the new data set with the following commands:

```
dataTry = 
  Import["C:\\Users\\user\\Desktop\\HystereseMitTab.txt", {"Data", {All}, {3, 6}}];
ListPlot @ dataTry
```

This returns a blank coordinate system without any data points. If I erase the semicolon after the first line Mathematica returns the list of the points to be plotted without plotting those so I assume something goes wrong whilst plotting and it's not something that came up after the excel export, but I might be wrong.

Googling did not help that much, so I am asking you guys if anyone can help me with this. Relatively new to Mathematica so the problem might have a trivial solution that I am just unable to come up with on my own.

Comment: Posting the data (or putting somewhere like pastebin) would make it easier for people to help.

Comment: @NVardan Welcome to Mathematica.SE. Start by taking time to read the FAQ. This site is a collaborative effort, so don't only ask, but also give, by answering questions in your area of expertise. Also important, when you see good Q&A, upvote them, it shows appreciation. And accept the answer which best answers your question. Again, appreciation, but also a sign for others that the problem has been solved. Enjoy.

Comment: @NVardan what does the output of `data` look like. I suspect there is an issue with the import: e,g. strings, missing values, array shape

Comment: This is the original file, the one that I can plot without any issues:  https://pastebin.com/eQuaK02n

This is the one that I have issues with:  https://pastebin.com/iV4K89nu

I tried to export as both a text file with tabs and as one with standard unicode-text. Neither version works.

Comment: @ubpdqn I don't get any error messages hence my confusion. Also, thank you for the welcome. Since I am new to Mathematica, I don't have any areas of expertise so the help I can offer is very limited, however I will try to do my best.

Comment: You data files seems to be Excel type. If so, I suggest you import your data from them manipulating Sheets, columns and rows easily. In addition, if you have those Excel files, it would be useful you provide them than TXT versions.

Answer (score 1):

I think the best way is to prepare you data file using Excel or some other software (as suggested by @José Antonio Díaz Navas). If you want to use your original data file you can, for example, import your data using `"Table"` format and process them a little in Mathematica.

```
data = Import["hystereseerror.txt", "Table", NumberPoint -> ","][[7 ;;]];
ListPlot@Transpose[{data[[All, 3]], data[[All, 5]]}]
```

[image]

Comment: Or more simply, `ListPlot@data[[All, {3, 5}]]`

Comment: Worked perfectly, thank you very much! I did prepare it with excel beforehand because I had to use the data I measured to calculate something before I would plot it, but I guess after exporting the data something did not go as I wanted it to so when I tried to use the original code with the new file and slight modifications it did not work. 

But your version worked perfectly! Thank you again!
Next time I will directly import the spreadsheet into Mathematica, it will probably work out way better!